# Advice on my project - email service provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

this is my first post on stack overflow.

First, I would like to apologize if previous posts solved a similar question but as you'll see, it can be a little tricky to search terms behind my question.

I just learned ruby on rails and I'm working on a project which requires a very good mailing tool.

Here's the actions of my project :

- User1 fills a form with a User2 email
- An email is automatically sent to UserB with inside a question and the answer needs to be form filled in the email by User2 (or
  maybe a    clicked image)

After that I need 2 things :

- collect email's input and data from User2
- resend automatically an email to User1 with the input and data (answer) from User2 email

Here's my 2 questions :

1. Using RoR, what email service can help me to create this scenario
   and get the job done ?
2. I know that as User1 is giving User2 email, it's not very "permission-based" but User2 has a real incentive to get this email, open it and complete it, so what about deliverability in this case ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a design question than an email service provider question. A solid email service provider is mailgun. [Here](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails) is their rails api docs.

The explanation above is a bit confusing but it sounds like there are two controller actions. Once to send the initial e-mail and then one to store user2's response to the database and send off another e-mail to user1.